# How to integrate card.io sdk in iOS hybrid app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, hybrid-mobile-app, card.io

I have hybrid iOS app and want to integrate card.io sdk to use credit card scanning functionality but cocoapod module have class having utilities written only.
How to present native(like opening credit card scanner) view if possible.
Kindly suggest as my module class is not view controller.

Comment: You should probably start by saying what hybrid framework you are using ... or if you are just rolling your own with a UIWebView.

Answer (score -1):

I am using sencha touch.I have third party container having pod modules.In these modules only objective-c h & m files resides and js file used for bridging.